# How to access prop from $(selector).each()

Tags: jquery, iteration

Here's the HTML fragment

```
<select multiple>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2" selected>Option 2</option>
    <option value="3" selected>Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Here's the script

```
$('select option').each(function(index, elem) {
    if (elem.prop('selected')) {
        // Find a checkbox somewhere in the page that correspond with the option
        // and then check it.
    }
});
```

This however throws `elem.prop is not a function`.

Even a simple `console.log(elem.prop('selected'))` is not working.

How can I go about this?

Comment: Can't you simply use `$('option:selected')` ?

Comment: @Baldráni there are 2 option selected

Comment: @guradio but no `multiple` attribute on the select. OP - are you trying to allow multiple selection?

Comment: @Rory McCrossan. Yes. I just forgot to put it there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is because `elem` references an Element, not a jQuery object. To do what you require you need to wrap `elem` like this:

```js
$('select option').each(function(index, elem) {
  var $elem = $(elem);
  if ($elem.prop('selected')) {
    console.log($elem.val());
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2" selected>Option 2</option>
    <option value="3" selected>Option 3</option>
</select>
```

However you should note that your loop is redundant. You can use the `:selected` selector and avoid the loop completely:

```js
var $elem = $('select option:selected');
console.log($elem.val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2" selected>Option 2</option>
    <option value="3" selected>Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: note: there are 2 selected option . i think iterating the whole option is needed

Comment: Well spotted, although the OP isn't using the `multiple` attribute, so only one value can be selected - the last one

Comment: yes i am not sure why he has that though maybe typo?

Comment: Possible - I'll leave the answer as it is for now, until the OP can clarify the intent

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('select option').each(function(index, elem) {
  if ($(elem).prop('selected')) {
    // Find a checkbox somewhere in the page that correspond with the option
    // and then check it.
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2" selected>Option 2</option>
    <option value="3" selected>Option 3</option>
</select>
```

You should place elem in `$()`